# How do I retrieve a subcollection of a document in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection with the following structure:

```
events > default > participants > participant1
                                > participant2
                 > date
```

etc.  So `events` is a collection, and it has a number of documents with random keys (I've used default as an example). Within "default" there are various fields, but also a subcollection of `participants`.

When I retrieve events/default I expected to retrieve the list of participants at the same time, but I only get back the fields (date etc) - how do I also get the "participants" collection at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore queries are shallow and do not consider documents in collections other than the one you are querying.  There are no SQL-like "joins" that merge documents from multiple collections.

If you query events, then you will only ever get documents in that collection.  If you want participants, you will need to make an additional query, using the full path of the subcollection, including its parent document ID.  For example, in JavaScript:

```
firestore.collection("events").doc(knownId).collection("participants").get()
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!